# Restful web application, Java or PHP?

Tags: java, php, android, rest, web-applications

I'm creating an Android application which will access data using a restful web application.
I have quite a lot of experience with Java, but minimal experience with PHP.

Having looked online, it is difficult to determine which language is more suitable, scalable, portable etc.

I'm hoping that the Application may one day have many concurrent users and therefore I need the most suitable option.

If anyone has any experience writing a web application in either language, I'd be really interested to hear about your experiences, and any problems you faced.. i.e. for a java web application do you need a tomcat server or another embeddded to server for it to be able to run?

Thanks, for any answers, Matt.

Comment: There's way too much in this question, but for one of the more specific parts, Spring Boot makes using an embedded server completely effortless; you just include Tomcat on the classpath. I personally prefer Spring MVC 4 for REST services, but Jersey and Grails are both popular on Java, and Dropwizard is gaining popularity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already have experience with java, I would suggest you use the following to build your REST services: http://restlet.com/

Its very easy, and efficient. The performance is very smooth. For PHP, you will have some learning curve, and also there is no standard. Mixing java with PHP is like combining a VERY STRICT LANGUAGE (java) with a VERY LENIENT LANGUAGE (PHP). So its safer to be on the same language.

Tutorials:

Official tutorials to get started: http://restlet.com/learn/tutorial/2.2/

Good step by step tutorial with screenshots and code snippets: http://java.dzone.com/articles/restlet-framework-hello-world

Comment: Thanks, I'll check restlet out!

Comment: I want to ask a question here: Is it preferable to use java instead of PHP in the server side part of Android application..(I mean, most of the tutorials available on internet are written for PHP).

Comment: Its written in PHP because PHP is easy to use. Use Slim (http://www.slimframework.com/) if you want to use PHP. The thing is, usually on the internet you will see the trend where PHP programmers are trying to develop android applications, whereas your case is different. That is the reason why I suggested java in the first place.

Comment: @DeeJay' thanks..can you suggest any site for that kind of tutorials?

Comment: @krupalshah Please check this link, I hope it helps: http://www.phpgang.com/how-to-create-restful-api-webservice-with-slim-php-and-mysql_588.html They show nice code examples and also you can download the source.

Comment: @DeeJay' umm...this is for PHP...I wanted for java implementation with reslet...thanks anyway

Comment: @krupalshah Sorry I assumed you are finally moving towards PHP :D Please see my answer updated.

Answer (score 3):

### **Short:**

Take JAVA!

Always choose the language you are comfortable with. Also I think Java is better suited in the end.

PHP isn't my favorit. Most of the people like it, because it is easy to start with. (It was also for me the second (non Browser) language I touched.)

**Framework Tips**

- WebFrontend: [Play Framework](https://www.playframework.com/)
- Back End&Scaleability: [AKKA](http://akka.io/)
- JSON: [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

### **Long:**

**Scaleability in the meaning to scale to lots of concurrent users:**, 
is more a architectonical issue, as a question for the right language. You can write scaleable software in any language. The difference isn't the scaleability of a language, but it could be the performance. One language will take longer for the same task as the other one. But you could always throw more Servers in, to scale out.

**Architectures** to consider if you want to **scale out**, are in my opinion **message based** designs. My favorite is the **actor model**, there is a very good framework for that in Java, the **akka** framework (production proved). But I think you first should get your software running. If you get enough users... scalability problems are the problems you like to have (they mean you have users).

Scaleable doesn't only mean, that you can scale to many concurrent users. **But the ability, to handle the complexity of the software or can handle concurrent development** and so on (your team will grow, thats also a problem to handle). In this topics Java is as clearly static typed OOP language, better suited.

**Also the performance** will not be as good as in Java (it is a interpreted language). But there are always options. Facebook started with PHP. In an interview one of the lead developers, told that PHP isn't that scaleable, because PHP wasn't designed for OOP. But the performance issue was handled, through writing a compiler for PHP (outputs C++). [If if find the link I will post it] .

Update the PHP Compiler is Called HipHop and it uses HHVM (Hiphop virtual machine), Facebook developed it after excessive CPU usage

Answer (score 2):

You can consider looking at https://jersey.java.net/ As a web container you can use anything like Tomcat. I have used Google App Engine in the past.

Answer (score 0):

To get started quickly with Java look into http://dropwizard.io/, using less EE frameworks and more standard Java.
Has Jersey for REST and is supereasy to run.